# ng-model value not updating from chosen plugin dropdown

Tags: angularjs, jquery-chosen

I have a jquery chosen plugin for searchable dropdown. Usualy i trigger a change update for the value to get updated. Here My ng-model is not getting updated. Kindly help.

```
<span> <form:select name="country" path="" id="country" 
                    class="searchBoxWidth" ng-model="CarrierDetails.country">
                    <form:options items="${countryList}" />
                </form:select>

$('#country').change(function(){
        $("#country").trigger("chosen:updated");

    })
```

Should i use something like $scope.apply or watch or digest. I wish for an angular solution .
Or should i assign it back like

```
$scope.CarrierDetails.country=$("#country:selected").val();
```

Comment: you must follow the angular ways to code in angular js. You should use chosen directive of angular. https://github.com/localytics/angular-chosen

Answer (score 1):

just better switch to **Angular-chosen** (AngularJS wrapper )

https://github.com/localytics/angular-chosen